# ASP.NET Telerik Batch Grid change ReadOnly cell through JS

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid

I use Telerik RadGrid with Batch mode and I would like to change my ReadOnly cell through JavaScript. Is there any possible way to do that? Im already changing my cell which is not ReadOnly and it works well. Im doing that like this:

```
class GridFactory {
    static GetGrid() {
        var grid = $find(GridID),
            batchManager = grid.get_batchEditingManager();

        if (batchManager === undefined)
            return null;
        else
            return new GetGrid();
    }
}

var gridInfo = GridFactory.GetGrid();
var aktivni = gridInfo.cell("aktivni");
    gridInfo.changeCell(aktivni, 'N');
```

This code works really well, but when I try to change ReadOnly cell it doesnt work. Is there any way how to change ReadOnly Cell value?
Thanks!